# operator precedence in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am confused about the rules for operator precedence in Haskell.
More specifically, why is this:

```
*Main> 2 * 3 `mod` 2
0
```

different than this?

```
*Main> 2 * mod 3 2
2
```

Comment: see also [prelude operator precedences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30288988/3041008)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Function calls bind the tightest, and so

```
2 * mod 3 2
```

is the same as

```
2 * (mod 3 2)
```

Keep in mind that `mod` is not being used as an operator here since there are no backticks.

Now, when `mod` is used in infix form it has a precedence of 7, which `(*)` also has. Since they have the same precendence, and are left-associative, they are simply parsed from left to right:

```
(2 * 3) `mod` 2
```

Answer (score 2):

2*3 = 6 and then `mod 2` = 3 with no remainder ... so `6 mod 2 = 0` is your answer there.
In your second case you are doing 2 * the result of `mod 3 2` which is `2 * 1 = 2`. Therefore your answer is `2`.... Your operator precedence remains the same, you just arranged it so the answers were expressed accordingly.