# Calculating index of symbol in list

Tags: haskell

I'm new with Haskell. Despite the fact that Hugs is old and is not supported anymore my university still uses it. Here is my code:

```
gio aso sia = jako aso sia 1
jako aso [] n = 0
jako aso (a:b) n = if a == aso then n else (jako aso b n+1)
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the index of first appearance of symbol in list. But it doesn't seem to work in case where I don't have such symbol. Instead of 0 it returns size of list. I could not understand why. P.S.: I need to know why my code doesn't work, not any other ways how to achieve the goal. Thanks.

Comment: `jako aso b n+1` is `(jako aso b n)+1`, and not `jako aso b (n+1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [operator precedence in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080128/operator-precedence-in-haskell)

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks a lot! Make it a answer and I'll confirm

Comment: You're welcome. I believe the question I suggested as a duplicate provides a good general explanation of the issue, and so rather than answering I will wait for others to confirm the duplicate.

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicated since when @Rasty was asking this  question, he probably not know that it is a operator-precedence problem, and knowing that question already solved his problem.