# Can't use dollar ($) instead of parens

Tags: haskell

I always try to get rid of parens where posible. Here is simple code:

```
groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems (x:xs) = (fst spaned) : groupElems (snd spaned) where
  spaned = span (== x) (x:xs)
```

It takes a list and returns list of grouped elems. Like this -

```
groupElems [1,2,2,2,4]
> [[1],[2,2,2],[4]]
```

And thas works fine. Now I try to replace parens with dollar:

```
groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems (x:xs) = (fst spaned) : groupElems $ snd spaned where
  spaned = span (== x) (x:xs)
```

But then I get strange (to me) error:

```
hello.hs:83:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a] -> [[a]]’
                  with actual type ‘[[a]]’
    • The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
      but its type ‘[[a]]’ has none
      In the expression: (fst spaned) : groupElems $ snd spaned
      In an equation for ‘groupElems’:
          groupElems (x : xs)
            = (fst spaned) : groupElems $ snd spaned
            where
                spaned = span (== x) (x : xs)
```

Is it possible to use dollar here?

Comment: Note that `(fst spaned)` doesn't need parentheses above. You can remove those parentheses without any `$`. For `snd spaned` instead, I don't think they can be removed easily.

Comment: Also, have to point this out every time: `$` has _nothing_ whatsoever to do with parentheses. You can _incidentally_ also use it to simplify expressions so they no longer require parentheses sometimes, but that's just because `$` is a low precedence operator.

Comment: @Cubic I know it, but nevertheless I try to get rid of parentheses throught this not trivial way, and this leads me to desperate attempts to put dollar almost everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

You get the error because of operator precedences. `$` has the lowest possible precedence, while function application has the highest possible. I.e. your original code:

```
(fst spaned) : groupElems (snd spaned)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(fst spaned) : (groupElems (snd spaned))
```

While your attempt to remove parens is grouped like:

```
((fst spaned) : groupElems) $ (snd spaned)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125395/haskell-operator-vs-function-precedence).

Answer (score 4):

Redefine (or rather replace) `spaned`, and you don't need to call `fst` or `snd`, eliminating the parentheses *and* the need for `($)`.

```
groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems all@(x:_) = s1 : groupElems s2 where
  (s1, s2) = span (== x) all
```