# Difference between mod in the beggining of the operation or `mod` in the middle

Tags: haskell, operators, modulo

I really don't know what's the difference between one method or another, but, in some operations ghci only works if I use one and in another operations it only works if I use the other!
Can somebody help me and explain me this?

Comment: Nothing, the two are, after the parsing phase identical. ``x `mod` y`` is equivalent to `mod x y`. It is frequently used to make things more readable, like ``x `elem` y``, or ``(==) `on` f``.

Comment: The only syntactical difference is that ``x `op` y`` acts as an operator, and thus has a different precedence level.

Comment: There is also the difference that `x \`f arg\` y` is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell operator vs function precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125395/haskell-operator-vs-function-precedence)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the precedence of functions in Haskell with the back ticks, just that, because some functions, like plus, times, minus, mod, are more natural understanding in the middle, if you create:

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus x y = x + y
```

In Haskell *white space* is function application, and functions are prefix by default:

```
$> plus 3 4
```

if you want it in the middle, one way is to use the back ticks to make it infix:

```
$> 3 `plus` 4
```

and you can use parenthesis to make an infix function prefix:

```
$> (+) 3 4
```

Comment: I think it becomes clear if you explain it like this: mod is a 2-parameter function while `mod` is the corresponding binary operator. That is, in general, back quotes gives us the binary operator corresponding to a 2-parameter function while parenthesis around a binary operator gives us the corresponding 2-parameter function. The function is partially applicable, as is the operator. If we write mod 3, we get a 1-parameter function. If we write (3 `mod`) we get a unary operator (this is called an operator section). The two forms have different use but compute the same results.

Comment: Ok, my back quotes disappeared... sigh.